# How to have an instance method modify object if it creates inner class?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have an object that I want to be modified when I call the appropriate instance method for it. (I think that is the correct vocabulary)

From one class, I am doing this:

```
 Pizza pizza = new Pizza();
 pizza.addTopping(Cheese);
 pizza.addTopping(Pepperoni);
 pizza.setCrustType("thick");
 pizza.make();
 pizza.putInOven();
```

Here's where things get interesting. So here's the `make()` method that is called above that is in the class `Pizza`.

```
 public void make()
 {  
      final Pizza pizza = this;
      pizza.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler()
      {             
           @Override
           public void onUpdate(float cookTime)
           {
                // need to do some modifications to pizza
                pizza.doSomething();
                pizza.doSomethingElse();
           }
      });
 }
```

In order to be able to access the pizza object inside the inner class, IUpdateHandler(), I have to set a `Pizza` object to `this`. But then, it also has to be `final` because you:

`Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method`.

Going back to my original code snippet, I still need to call `pizza.putInOven()` and have it be referencing the same `Pizza` object as all the other calls, but ***with the modifications from the*** `make()` ***method in effect***. Because I had to create a new `Pizza` object of type `final` in the method `make()` that is **no longer the same** object modified when I want to call `putInOven()`.

How do I solve this issue? If my question is not clear, I'll do my best to edit and restate, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the additional pizza variable because the code is already executed inside the pizza object.

```
public void make(){  
      registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler(){             
           @Override
           public void onUpdate(float cookTime){
                // need to do some modifications to pizza
                doSomething();
                doSomethingElse();
           }
      });
 }
```

Comment: Wow! I feel so dumb! I tried this, but I put `this.doSomething()` to which if course it complained that the `doSomething()` method was not of type `IUpdateHandler`. Once I omitted it everything is ok! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

> Because I had to create a new Pizza object of type final in the method make() that is no longer the same object modified when I want to call putInOven().

That's not true.

```
final Pizza pizza = this;
```

This line is NOT creating a new object as you are not using `new` operator. So, it's the same object referenced by `this` and hence your `putInOven` will see the changes done by `make` method.

Comment: Hmm... not sure I totally agree. I guess I didn't create a "new" object, but I most definitely created a new copy of the pizza object that is local to this methods scope, no? Therefore the changes will NOT be seen outside of this methods scope on the object?

Comment: @unexpected62 no you just created a reference that points to `this`

Comment: Only the reference (or pointer) to object is local to method. but it's the same object being modified by the new reference created.

Comment: REALLY. Wow. I'm learning C simultaneously as working on this so my brain is a little jumbled. So in java, without the `new` operator, the object itself persists through scope changes, but the reference to the object is local.

Comment: @unexpected62: Yes. and the place where object resides is called `heap` irrespective of whether object is created within method or as an instance field.